# Positioning nodes problem with default anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, anchor

Here is a MWE of my problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}

\begin{document}
\def\a{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  large block/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum width=\a,minimum height=2.5*\a,
                      outer sep=0pt},
  dot/.style={fill,shape=circle,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt},
  node distance=\a and \a
] 
  \draw[style=help lines,step=0.25cm] (-1.5,-2) grid (4.5,2);

  \node[large block] (G1) at (0,0) {$G_1$};
  \node[dot,fill=red] at (G1) {};
  \node[dot,above right=-0.5*\a and \a of G1,"above:$r_1$"] (r1) {};
  \draw[-latex] ([yshift=0.75*\a]G1.east) -- (r1);

  \node[large block] (G2) at (3,0) {$G_2$};
  \node[dot,fill=green] at (G2.center) {};
  \node[dot,above right=-0.5*\a and \a of G2.center,"above:$r_2$"] (r2) {};
  \draw[-latex] ([yshift=0.75*\a]G2.east) -- (r2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Altough the rectangles `G1` and `G2` seem to be positioned at the same y axis, depending if I choose `G1` or `G1.center` the point `r1` ends up on completly different y locations?

Also the black dot is slightly shifted and does not end up on the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `positioning` library, and that means node distances are measured between the borders of the nodes, not their center points. And when a node is positioned `above right` of `G1`, the distance is measured from the `north east` anchor of `G1`. So what you're seeing for G1 is the expected output. If you want distances to be measured from the center point of the nodes, you need the `on grid` option, as described in section 17.5.3 of the manual.

For some reason `on grid` didn't have the expected effect for `r2`, I don't know why. But you can achieve the same by adding `anchor=center` after the `above right`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\Unit{1cm} % \a is already defined
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  large block/.style={draw,thick,
                      on grid, % added
                      rectangle,minimum width=\Unit,minimum height=2.5*\Unit,
                      outer sep=0pt},
  dot/.style={fill,shape=circle,
              on grid, % added
              inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt},
  node distance=\Unit and \Unit
] 
  \draw[style=help lines,step=0.25cm] (-1.5,-2) grid (4.5,2);

  \node[large block] (G1) at (0,0) {$G_1$};
  \node[dot,fill=red] at (G1) {};
  \node[dot,above right=-0.5*\Unit and \Unit of G1,"above:$r_1$"] (r1) {};
  \draw[-latex] ([yshift=0.75*\Unit]G1.east) -- (r1);

  \node[large block] (G2) at (3,0) {$G_2$};
  \node[dot,fill=green] at (G2.center) {};
  \node[dot,above right=-0.5*\Unit and \Unit of G2.center,
        anchor=center,
        "above:$r_2$"] (r2) {};
  \draw[-latex] ([yshift=0.75*\Unit]G2.east) -- (r2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you remove the `center` anchor in `G2` the `r2` will be positioned correctly, no need for `anchor=center`. I also noticed that the positioning changes depending if I first declare `dot` or `above right=...` in the node, why is this so?

Comment: @Reza Well yes, then it's the same case as `G1`, but as I read the manual the result should have been identical also without `anchor=center`. For the last part, `above right` sets `anchor=south west`,  unless `on grid` is in effect, in which case the `center` anchor is used. If you have `dot` after `above right`, the `on grid` option hasn't been switched on yet, so the anchor is set to `south west`. I think. Anyways, you should study the appropriate section in the manual if you haven't already.